# Only apply css grid to first row

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following simple grid:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

I have a situation where I'm not able to edit the front-end markup. I'd only like the grid to be applied to the first 3 items. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason why the last three items can't be in their own grid row? What layout are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd like the first 3 items to be equally split, but the last 3 to be full width.

Comment: Seems pretty simple using `grid-template-areas`.

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look, thank you.

Comment: Sam, although my answer was accepted, I think you may want to mark Temani's or Suyash's instead. Even though mine does work, the other two are less markup and concise.

Comment: Thank you @disinfor. Great answers all round. I have some reading to do on grid ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply make each element to span 3 column starting from the fourth one. You don't even need to define any template. The implict grid will do it for you.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
}
.grid :nth-child(n + 4) {
  grid-column:span 3;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.grid li:nth-child(n+4) {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This won't work, as the OP said they can't change the markup, so targeting classes is not an option.

Comment: I changed the markup/CSS, now add an explanation to your answer

Comment: This is a much simpler version than mine. Very concise. Please add an explanation to why this code works. I think it's super valuable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example without using template areas, but rather repeating columns and rows, and then setting the start and stop point for each element (`grid-column`). You'll notice, I used `nth-child` to target the first three `li` and then used `1n+4` to target everything after the first three.

For `grid-template-rows` I set the repeat at 8, in the event you have more items in your list or if your list is dynamic.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.grid li:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.grid li:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}

.grid li:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 5/6;
}

.grid li:nth-child(1n+4) {
  grid-column: 1/6;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Setting the grid-template-row will make the height of the element bigger than its content (add border to notice this). You can replace it by `grid-auto-rows:1fr` in order to define 1fr to any new created row

Comment: Good catch. I updated the answer to reflect that. `grid-template-rows: 1fr` would also work.